# Using function return value as default template non-type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Here is my code:

```
bool test(){
    return true;
}


template<int asd[], bool T = test()>
void evenprocessor(){
    std::cout<<"this is called"<<std::endl;
};

int asd[] = {1,2,3};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    evenprocessor<asd>();
    return 0;
}
```

I was doing some testings for sfinae, I am curious if something like this is possible. Evaluating a function once the template is called. I get an error stating that *no matching function to call to evenprocessor*.

Am I doing something wrong or it's impossible to evaluate a function if it's used inside a function or template parameter? Something like this:

```
template<int asd[]>
void evenprocessor(char(*)[test()]){
    std::cout<<"this is called"<<std::endl;
};

int asd[] = {1,2,3};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    evenprocessor<asd>();
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error stating that says *variable or field evenprocessor declared void*. Why is it declared void?

Comment: You probably missed `constexpr` at `constexpr bool test() { return true;}`

Comment: Templates are for passing type information or counts. You are passing variables. Can you explain why the non-templated version (ie: void evenprocessor(int*) ) doesn't work for you?

Comment: For testing/educational purposes and to understand their behavior.

Comment: What you're doing doesn't make any sense. You pass type information using templates. In your example you're trying to pass a variable. This is not what templates are used for.

Comment: With Clang: `template argument deduction/substitution failed: call to non-constexpr function 'bool test()'`. With `constexpr` it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The first one did not compile for me. I had to change it to this, compiling for C++11. Declare the `test()` function as [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) to let the compiler know that it can be evaluated at compile time.

> Evaluating a function once the template is called.

You need to make sure that the function can be evaluated at compile time as mentioned before. Otherwise you cannot compile the program.

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr bool test(){
        return true;
}


template<int asd[], bool T = test()>
                             void evenprocessor(){
        std::cout << "this is called" << std::endl;
};

int asd[] = {1,2,3};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        evenprocessor<asd>();
        return 0;
}
```

The second code example does not make sense to me. What are you trying to achieve?

There are several errors I see.

- The parameter name is absent.
- The piece of code in the function operator brackets is expected to be a lambda function. What you probably were trying to achieve is to point to an array that holds one element of type `bool` with value `true`. Review your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

A template non-type argument must be a converted constant expression. An invocation of a function "other than a `constexpr` constructor for a literal class, a `constexpr` function, or an implicit invocation of a trivial destructor" is *not* a core constant expression ([expr.const]). In your cast, `test()` is *not* a core constant expression because it is *not* `constexpr`. The compile error indicates this pretty clearly:

clang's error:

```
main.cpp:8:30: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
template<int asd[], bool T = test()>
                             ^~~~~~
```

gcc's error:

```
main.cpp:9:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:8:34: error: call to non-constexpr function 'bool test()'
 template<int asd[], bool T = test()>
                                  ^
```

Simply fix `test`:

```
constexpr bool test() {
    return true;
}
```

The second example fails for the same reason. Array-bounds must be core constant expressions as well. If you fixed `test()` to be `constexpr`, then your code would fail for the obvious reason that:

```
main.cpp:16:5: error: no matching function for call to 'evenprocessor'
    evenprocessor<asd>();
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:9:6: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
void evenprocessor(char(*)[test()]){
     ^
```

Oh right, gotta pass in something:

```
evenprocessor<asd>(nullptr);
```

Now everything compiles.